# Evaluating $T(x,y) = ((K_h*K_g - K_g)*(K_h*K_g - K_g))(x-y)$?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, evaluation, convolution

Define $K_h$ as$$
K_h(x) = \dfrac{1}{h}K\bigg(\dfrac{x}{h}\bigg),
$$
where $K$ is the Gaussian function$$
K(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}.
$$

Define the function $T(x,y)$ by$$
T(x,y) = ((K_h*K_g - K_g)*(K_h*K_g - K_g))(x-y).
$$

This expression arises in the context of bootstrapping for kernel density estimation. How can this expression be evaluated in Mathematica?

Comment: Try: `k[x_] = 1/Sqrt[2 Pi] Exp[-x^2/2];
kh[x_] = 1/h K[x/h];
kg[x_] = 1/g K[x/g];
T[x_, y_] = ((kh[x] kg[x] - kg[x]) (kf[x] kg[x] - kg[x])) (x - y);
T[x, y]`

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

k[h_, x_] = PDF[NormalDistribution[0, h], x]

(* E^(-(x^2/(2 h^2)))/(h Sqrt[2 π]) *)
```

Assuming that the first part takes the argument `x - y` rather than being distributed across `x - y`

```
t[x_, y_] = ((k[h, #]*k[g, #] - k[g, #])^2) &[x - y] // Simplify

(* (E^(-(((g^2 + h^2) (x - y)^2)/(
  g^2 h^2))) (-1 + 
   E^((x - y)^2/(2 h^2)) h Sqrt[2 π])^2)/(4 g^2 h^2 π^2) *)
```